# Is there any way to index only new data in solr from java application

Tags: java, solr

I've got postgresql database which i have  indexed in solr and everything is OK. I've made java application which can add a new row in the database. So my question is is there any way I can index ONLY  this new row from my java application in solr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using DIH you can use [Incremental Indexing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Using_delta-import_command) to index just the changed data in Solr.

If you are using standalone java code, you can use [Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) libraries to interact with Solr to index individual Documents.